# best distributed version control for a small group project on windows?

Tags: version-control

whats the best distributed version control for a group project of 2 people coding on windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably Mercurial. It is known to support Windows well.

Git would be my personal preference, simply because it is somewhat more powerful than Mercurial, and its recent Windows support is good, but it will probably never be a 1st class Windows "citizen".

Comment: +1 works well on windows, most of my team members who couldn't use svn without tortoisesvn are comfortable with the base command line interface (augmented with selected extensions).

Comment: TortoiseHg made me finally switch to a distributed system. Git was just too much of an annoyance for me with the half done GUI.

Comment: Once you get over the initial hump of not having a GUI, Git is much faster. :)

Comment: I've just switched from CVS to Mercurial and find TortoiseHg pretty good. However, used to use SmartCVS which I found to be excellent. I noticed there's a Git equivalent, SmartGit. Looks like a fine GUI for Windows (and anything else; it's Java). http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Mercurial, with TortoiseHg as GUI: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

If you are going with git, check out TortoiseGit here: https://tortoisegit.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Mercurial for distributed development. It has a per-project repository structure and fits good to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Git](http://git-scm.com/), [mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) and [bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/) are the new boys on the distributed version control scene, but all of them are mainly used in a *nix environment. Git is particurlarly popular - it has big backing since Linus Torvalds invented it.

For a team of two working on Windows I see: small budget, limited specialization. So you may wantr to consider one of the standard workhorses: [CVS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) or SVN.

Although I personally would choose mercurial, I would recommend [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) to you: many companies offer free hosted SVN for your team size.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I am particularly fond of [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org) as it scales nicely from one person to large teams. You can also check out [Git](http://git-scm.com/) which is becoming quite popular.

Believe it or not VSS is still around and used for many projects (especially if its internal to a network) but I would not recommend it, unless you want to use Microsoft TFS (Team Foundation Server), but that will cost you some money to setup.

Comment: Git's Windows support is kinda sketchy though, isn't it? Bazaar and Mercurial have more focus on Windows support as far as I know. (And neither VSS or TFS are distributed, which is what the OP asked for)

Comment: cmd line git works perfectly on Windows. As far GUI clients Git Extensions is OK apparently, TortoiseGit(my preferred supplement to cmd git) is becoming better and better.

Comment: Setting up SVN is kind of a pain for only two people. For instance setting up the svn ignore line has to be done on each person's client, while the .gitignore file only has to be set up once and becomes part of the repo.

Comment: As far as I know TFS can be distributed, and if you only have two devs I am not sure what the context for distributed would be. VSS can also be distributed, even though its a total hack. I have not used Git, but I have seen a number of windows users who use it, so I assume its fairly stable.

Comment: SVN ignore lists can be set as SVN properties and enforced for all users.

Answer (score -1):

I'm voting for Git. I'm absolutely in love with it. Its GUI support is meh, but I find myself not missing one ever. I do use GITK often to graphically view branches.

Git has a very clean directory structure with all source control meta data in one folder. Merging and Branching is very nice, as is the "cherry-pick" option.